# Code First Parent/Child relationships when both parent and child use TPH inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am trying to map a parent/child collection scenario where both parent and child use TPH inheritance.  I have tried many scenarios--none of which has worked.  The key for me is that each parent can only have one type of child in the collection.  Below is a contrived example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public abstract class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrder : Order
{
    public bool Rush { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrder : Order
{
    public string Contact{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrderLine> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OrderLine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrderLine : OrderLine
{
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public virtual SalesOrder Order { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseOrderLine : OrderLine
{
public int VendorID { get; set; }
    public virtual PurchaseOrder Order { get; set; }
}
```

The SalesOrder and PurchaseOrder class use are mapped to an Order table using TPH.  And the SalesOrderLine and PurchaseOrderLine are mapped to an OrderLine table using TPH.

Does EF support this and, if so, how can I acheive it?

Comment: EF supports inheritance in this fashion. You've not documented why you think this wont work. But I created a test and it seems to work fine.

Comment: @Ryan Amies could you post your results as an answer? I'd be interested to see this working as I can't achieve the desired result. I agree the question is a bit unclear but my understanding is that the OP wants to map Order, SalesOrder and PurchaseOrder to a single table and OrderLine, SalesOrderLine and PurchaseOrderLine to a single table whilst still maintaining the polymorphic navigation properties. The default conventions create 3 tables which I don't think is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Benjamin I think the issue you are having is the abstract keyword. It's not necessary and might be confusing EF. I am currently working on a project which has a similar structure.

Comment: @Ryan Amies I've tested this again this morning and noticed that if I include DbSet<Order> and DbSet<OrderLine> properties on my context EF creates 2 tables instead of 3. I'm not sure that abstract modifier makes any difference; the same table structure is generated with and without the abstract modifier. I can't say whether it is necessary or not as it's not my code, I'm guessing the OP doesn't want to be able to directly instantiate the Order and OrderLine classes which does make sense.